# Big Query takes too long for simple query

Tags: google-bigquery

Simple count query takes amazingly long time to accomplish.
Am I doing something wrong?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLE`
```

(if someone from bigquery hears this: 
jobid: southamerica-east1.bquxjob_6a6df24d_16dfdbe0b54)

Comment: How big is your table? LIMIT only limits the output

Comment: `Either` you are missing something from your real query to present `OR` just simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE` will do the same - you don't need LIMIT here at all - as it returns just one row with table's row count. and in reality - it never actually touches the table and rather using meta-table - that is why the cost of such query is zero

Comment: Sorry guys, the limit there was an error, I have pasted after I came back to this window.

I have just ran another one, please take a look:
https://pasteboard.co/IDYSvJ1.png

Comment: Took 3'44" 
Processed 270mb
Billed for 270mb

Comment: @Bobbylank 1111998 records

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant sorry, I didn't run with the LIMIT :/

Comment: so, another option for this to happening is if your table is actually external table and not native BigQuery table. For external tables meta-tables are not being maintained thus the cost and performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for a query running slow in BigQuery, as mentioned in the comments - if your table is an external table, that might cause an issue as well. If timing is critical for you and the queries you have are extremely simple, you might want to consider using Cloud SQL which is a realtime database.

BigQuery is normally used for larger more complex queries over very large datasets. If you have a support package, you might want to reach the Google Cloud Support team to have a look at the query to understand why it is running so slow.

Another workaround, just in case you only want to know the number of rows, could be to query the metadata:

```
SELECT table_id, row_count, size_bytes
FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.__TABLES__` where table_id = 'your_table'
```